# Is my internal hard drive dead?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, acer-aspire

I have a 500GB seagate internal hard drive in my Acer Aspire V 15 Nitro. Without dropping the laptop or anything, just letting it to sleep mode overnight, I open it to find no bootable device error. I had recently ran the "CrystalDiskInfo" software which showed my hdd in a green status.

I tried letting the battery drain completely before plugging it to power and running it again but with no result. The scary part is I also just tried connecting it with a SATA-USB cable to my desktop but it did not even recognised it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: run hdd diagnostic in bios and check.

Comment: Try resetting your BIOS.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did not have a raid or something but still I tried it. Also I don't have a diagnostic section in my BIOS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your course of investigation was correct: It reveals that your hard disk has at least failed to an extent that no web-prescribed answer can help.

Waste no time and take your drive to an authorized repair center.

I hope you have backup.

Comment: I have a made a back up but that was quite a while ago. I was wondering since when I am connecting the hdd and there is no sound, we can exclude the head problem. Additionally I don't think its the firmware as I had not made a recent update, so most probably its the circuit, is there any way to verify that?

Comment: There is but I doubt you have the necessary tools.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try looking more into it and in case it really is dead and is not infected with any bugs like "BSY bug" I'll come back and accept your answer.